# Why was this question put on hold as "too broad"?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

This question was put on hold as too broad:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540550/how-to-get-a-lossless-jpeg-compression-on-ios

Here is what I have done to try to get it taken off hold:

1. Commented on it addressing the concerns of the "Too Broad" paragraph of the instructions,
2. Changed the question a bit,
3. Flagged the question for moderator review.

I checked the moderator's tag history and he does not have a lot of experience with iOS.  I suspect that he might have missed that it was an iOS question and maybe flagged it too quickly.  If so it is an honest mistake but is hurting my chance at getting an answer.

Comment: `I suspect that he might have missed that it was an iOS question` As it says iOS in the title, I doubt that is the case. Rather, Andrew is an experienced moderator who can recognize off topic questions on any tag.

Comment: David, He did not take it as off topic.  He tagged it as too broad.

Comment: Kudos for coming here and asking productively about this, with not a single whiff of sarcasm or aggression. You're simply asking if either you or I made a mistake. I give kudos for this because it's often hard for people to do this in this manner. +1

Comment: Also, @DavidRobinson was wrong in the detail of what I closed as specifically, but I (somewhat self-servingly) think his note still applies.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks for working to keep stackoverflow "clean".  I have pulled the original question now that I understand what I am doing wrong.  I will resubmit it with my new understanding of the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are many valid answers to your question

> Are there other ways to get a lossless JPEG compression on iOS?

On StackOverflow there should be a specific situation with a specific answer. Not to mention that you asked other questions in the same question. A better question is:

> How would you get lossless JPEG compression on iOS?

Or

> Is there an alternate way to get lossless JPEG compression on iOS?

Also try removing the question that asks how lossless the compression is. Or make it the main question and ask the other question in a separate SO Question.

Comment: Your suggestions are all good.  I have accepted this answer and will submit single question.  I find it interesting that the alternative you are suggesting as better is exactly the title on the question.

Comment: `s/StackOverflow/Stack Exchange/` is not unique to SO

Answer (score 14):

The question being about iOS programming has nothing to do with why the question was too broad. This is why the question was too broad:

1. You ask two different questions.
2. You want someone to read an entire wikipedia article and say if it is correct.
3. You ask for *an* algorithm, which basically opens it up to anything.
4. The best answer to this would be a book...

Comment: What I learned from your answer is that I should not link to external resources and make sure my question is self contained.  I also learned that I should make it clear that I am not asking for an algorithm.  I intended to ask for a library or method call.  Thank you for posting a response so I can actually learn something rather than having to guess why people are down voting.

Comment: Be careful, library recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @MichaelPotter It's OK to quote/link external resources and ask about information in them; but it needs to be *specific*, and directly related to a current code writing issue you are having.